# Page Speed Small Page size vs number of Dom Elements

Tags: performance, loading, pagespeed

I have a question in regards to page speed of a website. See I have a picture with a original size of 100k that is use in 3 different location in a page. And in the 3 different location the size of the picture is different. The largest size of the 3 location being the 100k pic. When I ran Chrome page speed, it recommends me to serve scale image for the other 2 smaller size location.

I would like to ask if the picture has only 1 size of 100K, in 3 picture location does the browser fetch the image from the server 3 times or just once?

This lead to my question now is should I serve scaled image and have more dom elements but reduce page size OR should I serve the 100K image and the the browser fetch only once?

If I were to serve scaled image then the browser will have to request for 3 different size of the same image from the server which may increase the time to load rather than reducing it.

Comment: This is really a question about web development.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you serve the image as cacheable (this is the default) the browser will only download it once. So it is better to reference only one version of the image.

Comment: Roger, understand what you mean. I try same image with different size and realise that it is slower than just getting 1 size for all.